# React.js zooming animation on a particular div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two div components let us say that is, div1 & div2 and each div has an overlay div let us call them overlayDiv1 & overlayDiv2.

Now I have to animate it like that when I hover over div1, overlayDiv1 should zoom and when I hover over div2 OverlayDiv2 should zoom.

Please help me to achieve this in React.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` and create the elements dynamically like this:

```js
var numbers = [...Array(100).keys()];

var App = () => {
    return(
    <div className="container">
      {numbers.map( el => (
        <div className="inner">
          <div id={'d'+el} className="d">
              Div{el}
          </div>
          <div id={'od1'+el} className="od">
              overlayDiv{el}
          </div>
        </div>
       ))}
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  margin:20px 0px;
}

.d {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.od {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.d:hover+.od,
.od:hover {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: I have to make it in such a way if I have 100 divs and 100 overlay divs each having seperate key and IDs, then how should I do it without hard coding for each div.

Comment: Is there a way you can help me.... This question in terms of hooks.... Like using hooks I am able to achieve this

Comment: you want to achieve this using hooks. right?

Comment: Yes, using hooks